# C++ static data member initialization oddity

Tags: c++, initialization

I tried this with gcc-10.1 using `-std=gnu++17` and `-std=gnu++2a` options. This code snippet will not compile, if line A is uncommented:

```
struct Vec3f {
  float x, y, z;
  Vec3f(float x, float y, float z) : x(x), y(y), z(z) {};
};

struct S {
  static inline Vec3f a{1, 1, 1};
  static inline auto b = Vec3f(1, 1, 1);
  static inline Vec3f c(1, 1, 1);  // Line A
};

int main(int, char**) {
  Vec3f c(1, 1, 1);
  return c.z;
}
```

producing this error:

```
[build] ../main.cpp:16:25: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
[build]    static inline Vec3f c(1, 1, 1);
[build]                          ^
[build] ../main.cpp:16:25: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before numeric constant
```

despite `Vec3f c(1, 1, 1);` being happily used inside `main` function. Is there any rhyme or reason to it?

Comment: Because it's not a legal way to initialize a static class member.

Comment: @JHBonarius Why not? Is it buried somewhere deep in C++ legalese? Is there a good reason for this irregularity?

Comment: Aggregate initialization is the odd one out here. Normally assignment would always be required.

Comment: Seems to have worked for me... But then I spotted the uncomment line A bit. Do idiots like me a favour and post the non-working version, please.

Comment: @user4581301 Done. Sorry for the confusion.